# Warning: Illegal string offset of 'surname'

Tags: php, search, select, warnings

I'm trying to create a searchengine, to search members but when I execute the searchquery it gives me the error above. The error is about the last line in the code

Also the results are not really right.. it gives me the first characters of every word in the columns

So when I typ in 'Jan' or 'Vandenbergh' (first name, family name) it gives me J (first character from Jan, V (Vandenbergh) and so it goes on. With every character it gives an error.

The result of the selectquery:

```
'SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE name = 'jan' OR surname ='jan''
```

This is my function:

```
public function Search($searchinput)
    {
        $db = new Db();
        $select = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE name = '" . $searchinput . "' OR surname ='" . $searchinput . "'";
        var_dump($select);
        $result = $db->conn->query($select);
        return $data=$result->fetch_assoc();

    }
```

This is what the action button does:

```
if(isset($_POST["btnSearch"])){
    try {
        $searchinput = $_POST['btnSearch'];
        $searchresult = $user->Search($searchinput);
    }
    catch(exception $e){
        $feedback = $e->getMessage("no results");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="btnSearch" placeholder="search"/>
            <input type="submit" value="search members" />

      </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach ($searchresult as $result) {            
echo "<div><p>" . $result['surname']  . "</p></div>"; } ?> </div>
```

Comment: Does the warning only occur on initial page load (when `$searchresult` is not set, since `!isset($_POST["btnSearch"])`) or is it also on form submit / page reload?

Comment: When $searchresult is not set it gives this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\Stimulus\groups.php on line 75, what reffers to: foreach ($searchresult as $result), after the form submit it gives the error above

Comment: `->fetch_assoc()` only returns 1 row, not an array of rows. How many results do you want / expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP

```
public function Search($searchinput)
{
        $db = new Db();
        $select = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE name = '" . $searchinput . "' OR surname ='" . $searchinput . "'";
        $result = $db->conn->query($select);
        return $result;
}

if(isset($_POST["btnSearch"])){
try {
    $searchinput = $_POST['btnSearch']; // remember to filter that variable since you can be easily attacked
    $searchresult = $user->Search($searchinput);
}
catch(exception $e){
    $feedback = $e->getMessage("no results");
}
```

}

HTML

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="btnSearch" placeholder="search"/>
            <input type="submit" value="search members" />

      </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <?php
        if(is_object($searchresult))
            while($row = $searchresult->fetch_array()) {            
                 echo "<div><p>" . $row['surname']  . "</p></div>"; 
            } 
    ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: This one is working, really thanks .. so what did you do in the while loop with the fetch_array()?

Comment: This loop is nearly the same as `foreach()`, I just prefer that way. Also, `fetch_array()` will fetch next `$row` each loop, and not one `$row` for whole loop. Also remember to filter the `$searchinput = $_POST['btnSearch'];` as I commented.

Comment: For now depends on the plugins you are using, but mysql_real_escape_string or mysqli_real_escape_string. In the future, please read about prepared statements and PDO since they are the best at security.

Comment: Oh! I didn't see it, but before I do the action it gives a warning on the while loop: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49280/discussion-between-ailvenge-and-marnix-verhulst)

Answer (score 1):

[`->fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) only returns 1 row, not an array of rows, so `$searchresult` is a 1 level array, not an array of arrays, so you would have accessed it as `$searchresult['surname']`

Based on your comments that you want 1 or more results, in your function change

```
return $data=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

to [`->fetch_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

```
return $data=$result->fetch_all(); // you could also do ->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

Also, add an `isset()` around your results -

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    if(isset($searchresult)){
       foreach ($searchresult as $result) {            
          echo "<div><p>" . $result['surname']  . "</p></div>"; 
       }
    } ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Before the click it's still giving this: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
after the isset it gives an error to the fetch_all, namely:  Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on a non-object